# Hide all unselected edges in pyvis network graph

Tags: python, graph, data-visualization, pyvis

I have built a network graph using `pyvis` and it's very cluttered, as most of its nodes are connected (like the one on the left image but with more nodes and edges). Is it possible to only display the edges that connect selected nodes in `pyvis` (something like the right image if the leftmost node is selected)?

EDIT:
I found that there are options to tweak the behavior of edges when they are selected in [vis.js documentation](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/edges.html), but it doesn't seem like I can access these properties through python...

[image]